# What is sytanx for -> in linked list python

Tags: python, linked-list

Hey everyone I am trying to print (2->None, 3) in the linked list below, but am getting a syntax error. can someone please help me with this syntax cannot find on google for some reason. Code below:

```
class Node(object):

   def __init__(self, data=None, next_node=None):
       self.data = data
       self.next = next_node

def Insert(head, data):
    if head == None:
        head = Node(data)
        print(head)
    else: 
        current = head 
        while current.next != None: 
            current = current.next 
        current.next = Node(data)
    return head
print Insert(2->None, 3) # -> is bringing a syntax error, how do I write this in python 2.7?
```

Comment: `->` doesn't exist in Python Syntax . What do you try to do with `2->None` ? What result do you expect ?

Comment: @furas is there something similar to it? I'm trying to print this input: 2 --> NULL, data = 3 outcome:  2 --> 3 --> NULL in sublimetext.

Comment: If you want to pass in none, simply pass in `None`: Insert(None, 3). Python doesn't have pointer in the sense your thinking about.

Comment: When you say `2->None` are you thinking of the syntax of another language? What language... I can't see what you want from the example.

Comment: @Johnny: What do you think `->` even means? Asking us the right syntax for `->` is like asking us for the Japanese translation of "fishbob"; without any idea of what you're even trying to express, we can't tell you how to correctly express it.

Comment: problem is I don't know what you expect on `2->None`. Do you try to create two nodes, first with `2` and second with `None` or what ?

Comment: @AnthonyPham: But using `->` like that makes no sense in C either, for at least 3 reasons, so that doesn't really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, I think your confused about how to implement a linked list in the first place. If you want a linked list in the form of:

`[2] -> [3] -> [None]`

Then you need to insert each element backwards. First `None` then `3` then `2`. You also need to make your insert method *inside* of a class because you need to save state. Here is what I'd recommend instead:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data, next_node=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next_node = next_node

# Create a class not a function because we need to save state
# More specficly, we need to create a "global" variable which 
# keeps track of the head of the linked list.
class LinkedList(object): 
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    # Put the insert function inside of of the class.
    # That way, we can save and load the state of self.head.
    def insert(self, data):
        new_node = Node(data, self.head)
        self.head = new_node

# demo
ll = LinkedList()
# insert the elements in the reverse order you want  
# them to appear.
ll.insert(None)
ll.insert(3)
ll.insert(2)

print("Head:", ll.head.data) # Head: 2
print("Middle:", ll.head.next_node.data) # Middle: 3
print("Tail:", ll.head.next_node.next_node.data) # Tail: None
```

Also, I recommend to a little research as well. Such as [this article](http://quiz.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-2-inserting-a-node/). Or just google [*Linked List in Python*](https://www.google.com/search?q=Linked+List+in+Python&oq=Linked+List+in+Python&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j0l3.777j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and browse over some of the results.

Comment: thank you, that is much more indepth than the hackerrank challenge lol. @leaf

Comment: My pleasure, @Johnny.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you just want to insert `None` as the first argument as what @leaf said. In that case, just directly use `None`:

```
print Insert(None, 3)
```

`->` doesn't exist in Python as of now.  This is @leaf's comment:

> If you want to pass in none, simply pass in `None`: `Insert(None, 3)`. Python doesn't have pointer in the sense your thinking about.